# Cassandra Faceting Not Working After Spring Upgradation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr, cassandra

I have upgraded Spring from **1.5.2 to 2.5.5** so the Cassandra is also got upgraded.

I am using Cassandra Repository and writing native queries.

before upgrading, the below query was giving the data in **facet_fields** column but after upgrading I am getting data in **reference** column

**@Query(select reference from tablename where solr_query='{"q": "date:[2020-06-01T04:00:00Z TO 2020-06-05T03:59:59Z] " , "facet":{"field" : "reference"}}')**

I have executed the above query in datastax there I am getting the value under **facet_field** column only but, from application it is coming under **reference**.

I am sure this is due to spring upgradation, could anyone please let me know the solution or any alternative for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. After doing lot of R&D I did not found anything related to this. So, I have handled this scenario in code itself.